htaccess is rewriting all subsequent urls to same page
My htaccess is correctly implementing for the the first file i write. But for subsequent files it is redirecting every other redirect to same page. The article rewrites are working fine but other redirects landing on the article page too. Even contact pages are landing on the article redirect. I have developed 2 different pages article.php and news.php. I want the url's to be as follows:
mywebsite.com/article1
mywebsite.com/news1
Where article1 and news1 are values fetched by the sql.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif|svg)$
RewriteRule ^(ajax|assets|auth)($|/) - 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+) article.php?article=$1 
RewriteRule ([^/]+) news.php?news=$1



The article rewrites are working fine but other redirects landing on the article page too. Even contact pages are landing on the article redirect.

Well, yes. ([^/]+) matches any character except / one or more times. You effectively redirect everything to article.php, so things behaves exactly the way you've told it to.
You have to figure out how your webserver should know what you want to send to article.php, and what to send to news.php. Then you'll have to create a regexp to match whatever pattern you pick.
